# Issue while trying to connect qc using OTA with java from MAC

Tags: java, macos, ota, hp-quality-center

I am trying to connect `QC` using `OTA` with `Java` and I am executing from Mac machine. It is unable to establish a successful connection whereas I have tried the same piece of code in Windows and it is working fine. Can anyone throw some light on how to enable this from Mac?

Exception stack trace:

```
[junit] Exception in thread "Com4J shutdown hook" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com4j.COM4J
[junit]            at com4j.COM4J$3.run(COM4J.java:476)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a COM library in Mac OS? Maybe you should try using the REST API of Quality Center (if you use QC11).

Comment: It is not since the OTA dll is not supporting in Mac. So I am using QC10. Can you please let me know whether rest api services available in QC10. if so can you please throw some info on that.

Comment: I think the REST API was introduced with QC11.